# IntelliJ - Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP' does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Created a spring boot project in IntelliJ but getting error while running.

Below is the error

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP' does not exist
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at com.example.studentapplication.StudentApplication.main(StudentApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP' does not exist
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.system.ApplicationTemp.getTempDirectory(ApplicationTemp.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.system.ApplicationTemp.getPath(ApplicationTemp.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.system.ApplicationTemp.getDir(ApplicationTemp.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.SessionStoreDirectory.getValidDirectory(SessionStoreDirectory.java:46) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory.getValidSessionStoreDir(AbstractServletWebServerFactory.java:306) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory.getValidSessionStoreDir(AbstractServletWebServerFactory.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configurePersistSession(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureSession(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:390) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:205) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `Temp directory 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP' does not exist` maybe you should create this directory?

Comment: created but did not work

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The solution for me was to open the `TEMP` folder manually in order to get privileges.

What I did was:

1. WIN+R and go to `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` (or just navigate there through
   explorer)
2. A Windows warning message will appear stating that "You don't have permissions to view this folder etc."
3. Click "Continue" (you should have Administrator rights)
4. Run the application through IntelliJ again.

Since IntelliJ runs under your Windows account, there should be no errors produced anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you don't have privileges' to access the TEMP folder .

> Solution to this if you are using IntellijIDE --> Edit Run
> Configuration --> VM option update below -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:<your
> path>

For example

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\user\mytempclass
```

Answer (score -1):

I also meet the problem when using devtools. I had set the TEMP environment variable for using Latex. Maybe it is the cuase.